# Dynkin diagram of Basic classical simple Lie superalgebras

Tags: reference-request, root-systems, lie-superalgebras

Let $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak g_0 \oplus \mathfrak g_1$ be a basic classical simple Lie superalgebra with the root system $\Delta = \Delta_0 \cup \Delta_1$ and Dynkin diagram $\Gamma$. It is well-known that $\Delta_0$ is the root system of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g_0$ which itself is the disjoint union of two irreducible root system.

My question is, what is the relation between the Dynkin diagram of these two irreducible root systems and $\Gamma$? More precisely, the connected components of $\Gamma$ obtained by removing the odd vertices will give the Dynkin diagram of these two irreducible root systems?

My question may not be precise as I am new to superalgebras, so I am requesting the experts to edit the question appropriately.

Thank you.